# Exculde fields in json based on some condition

Tags: json, jackson

I have a list of objects of a class which I am rendering as json to the browser. Now there are certain attributes in the objects which I want to exclude from the json response if certain condition is not met.

So those attributes will be there for some objects of the list and will be absent for the other objects of that list.

How do I achieve that?

Mine is a spring boot application. Jackson is being used.

I am using Transformer for converting Entity to Bean and then ResponseEntity to convert the bean to json.

Please suggest possible solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make those values (which you want to be excluded) as null and then make use of the `@JsonInclude` annotation to suppress all null values.

> ```
> @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
> class Foo {
>   String bar;
> }
> ```

you can exclude `null` values for specific fields too (As opposed to excluding null values for the entire object)

> ```
> public class Foo {
>     private String field1;
>     private String field2;
>
>     @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
>     private String field3;
>     ...
>     ...
> }
> ```

**in version 2.x+** the syntax for this annotation is:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

Or you can also set the **global option**:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

In a Spring Project, `objectMapper` is the singleton instance of class `ObjectMapper` which you can either `@Autowired` or get from ApplicationContext

Comment: I applied this annotaion on top of my attribute. But it is giving me compilation error on that annotation. 

However, the jackson jar is there in my maven dependencies list.

How do I resolve that?

Comment: I am using jackson-annotations-2.6.4.jar

Comment: Ok I got it working using this annotation :

@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL) 

But it says JsonSerialize is a deprecated class. Do we have a better alternative for the same?

Comment: **in version 2.x+** the syntax for this annotation is:

    `@JsonInclude(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`

Or you can also set the **global option**:

    `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);` Updated the answer as well

Comment: Problem solved with the first solution @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) . There was some issue in my project due to which the jar was not getting picked earlier. But it served the purpose. Thanks a lot :)